# Is it possible to merge multiple json files with their parent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 100 JSON files need to merge to 1 JSON file. basically I want to put [] around 100 files and append them all into 1 file.

Each file has the same structure as follow:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Student",
        "children": [
            {
                "ID": "111",
                "Name": "John",
                "Pattern": "DA0"
            },
            {
                "ID": "222",
                "Name": "Tom",
                "Pattern": "DA0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have the following code to achieve this but there is an error for JSON encode? Please have a look:

```
import glob
import json 

    read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
    output_list = []
    
    with open(read_files, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        for f in read_files:
            with open(f, "rb") as infile:
                output_list.append(json.load(infile))
    
    all_items = []
    for json_file in output_list:
        all_items += json_file['items']
    
    textfile_merged = open('merged.json', 'w')
    json.dump({ "items": all_items }, textfile_merged)
    textfile_merged.close()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combine.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open(read_files, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: So, what exactly is not clear about the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The `glob.glob("*.json)` returns a list of path names per the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). So your code `with open(read_files, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:` will not work properly.

Try something like:

```
import glob
import json

read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
output_list = []

for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))

# rest of your code
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: The error indicates that you are attempting to load data that does not conform to JSON.  It looks like the file is empty based on `1from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.  You should probably add some sanity checking before attempting to load the JSON data.  You can check that the size of the file is larger than 0 as a start.